# Having trouble moving between rooms with python

Tags: python

So I'm pretty new to python and I'm having the hardest time with getting my code to work for moving between rooms! When I run my code, the loop just iterates down the list instead of in the direction the user would input. No matter what direction is put in, the rooms go from 'Great Hall' to 'bedroom' to 'cellar' and then back to 'Great Hall'. Even when a direction that's not in the current room is entered it prints 'You cannot go that way' but still moves down the rooms list. What am I doing wrong?? I can't figure it out.

```
rooms = {

    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}

current_room = rooms['Great Hall']


def move_rooms(current_room, directions):
    current_room = rooms[current_room]
    new_room = current_room[directions]
    return new_room

while True:
    for current_room in rooms:
        print('You are in the', current_room)
        directions = input('Which way would you like to go: North, South, East, or West?')
        if directions in rooms[current_room]:
            move_rooms(current_room, directions)
        elif directions not in rooms[current_room]:
            print('You cannot go that way.')
```

Comment: Omg, it worked. I've been pouring over this for hours. Thank you so much! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `current_room` doensn't get updated. Remove the for loop and assign the return value of the `move_rooms` function to `current_room`

```
rooms = {

    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}

current_room = 'Great Hall'


def move_rooms(current_room, directions):
    current_room = rooms[current_room]
    new_room = current_room[directions]
    return new_room

while True:
    print('You are in the', current_room)
    directions = input('Which way would you like to go: North, South, East, or West?')
    if directions in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = move_rooms(current_room, directions)
    elif directions not in rooms[current_room]:
        print('You cannot go that way.')
```

Comment: Suggestions to further improve OP's code: rename the local `current_room` as it means something different from the argument; replace the `elif` predicate with a simple `else` as it is always true.